# SPARQL query: using VALUES inline data or UNION with bigdata store

Tags: sparql, union, rdf, blazegraph

I have a dataset that looks a bit like:

```
<item1> <isLocated> <someAddress>
<item2> <isLocated> <someAddress>
<item3> <isLocated> <someOtherAddress>
```

I want to be able to use SPARQL to answer the question:

"Which items will I find at someAddress or someOtherAddress?"

I could use a UNION like this:

```
SELECT ?item
{
    { ?item <isLocated> <someAddress> }
    UNION { ?item <isLocated> <someOtherAddress }
}
```

But I think this will become pretty messy when I start talking about 100's or 1000's of addresses.

I think the VALUES inline data might be more suitable than a heap of UNION queries.
I've tried writing the following query but my RDF store/engine (bigdata) seems to choke on it:

```
SELECT ?item
{
    ?item <isLocated> ?loc .
}
VALUES (?loc) { (<someAddress>) (<someOtherAddress>) }
```

(based on http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data)

The error I get from bigdata is:
Lexical error at line 5, column 7. Encountered: " " (32), after : "VALUES"

Am I forming this query correctly?
Is using a UNION or VALUES more appropriate?

It seems no matter how I format this query (based on the w3 examples in the link above) I get similar Lexical errors.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say that Bigdata does not yet support the `VALUES` clause. This is a brand new feature introduced in the latest SPARQL working draft (published just weeks ago), so quite naturally several tools will not yet support it.

You could try using `BINDINGS` instead (this is roughly the same feature from previous working drafts, which was replaced).

Comment: Reading the bigdata doc implies that they almost fully support SPARQL 1.1 [link](http://www.bigdata.com/bigdata/blog/). But I'm guessing you are right. I replaced `VALUES (?loc)` with `BINDINGS ?loc` in my query and it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they do, but SPARQL 1.1 is a work in progress, not a fixed standard yet.

Answer (score 3):

You've mixed up the syntax a little. Either use:

```
VALUES ?loc { <someAddress> <someOtherAddress> }
```

which is a special form for a single variable, or:

```
VALUES (?loc) { ( <someAddress> ) ( <someOtherAddress> ) }
```

the general form.

You could also try [`IN`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in)

```
FILTER (?loc IN ( val1, val2, ...))
```

Comment: You are right I did mess up the syntax in my post, when I use the correct syntax I still get the same error.

Comment: I was running the queries with the correct syntax though (tried both).  'FILTER' does produce a correct set of results.  Both you and @JeenBroekstra gave answers that give correct solutions.

Comment: Yep, there's been some back and forth on the name of bindings / values. It's cheap to change, so unfortunately it has changed. (The semantics have changed too, but you probably wouldn't notice)